# Using regex to extract all the html attrs

Tags: python, html, regex

I want to use `re` module to extract all the html nodes from a string, including all their attrs. However, I want each attr be a group, which means I can use `matchobj.group()` to get them. The number of attrs in a node is flexiable. This is where I am confused. I don't know how to write such a regex. I have tried `</?(\w+)(\s\w+[^>]*?)*/?>'` but for a node like `<a href='aaa' style='bbb'>` I can only get two groups with `[('a'), ('style="bbb")]`.
I know there are some good HTML parsers. But actually I am not going to extract the values of the attrs. I need to modify the raw string.

Comment: FFS... http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Consider using HTML parsers instead of Regex. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Normal the first match is overwritten by the second.

Comment: Why do you need to modify the raw string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

To capture an infinite number of attributes it would need to be a two step process, where first you pull the entire element. Then you'd iterate through the elements and get an array of matched attributes.

regex to grab all the elements: `<\w+(?=\s|>)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?>`

[image]

regex to grab all the attributes from a single element: `\s\w+=(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*)(?=\s|>)`

[image]

## Python Example

See working example: http://repl.it/J0t/4

**Code**

```
import re

string = """
<a href="i.like.kittens.com" NotRealAttribute=' true="4>2"' class=Fonzie>text</a>
""";

for matchElementObj in re.finditer( r'<\w+(?=\s|>)(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*?>', string, re.M|re.I|re.S):
    print "-------"
    print "matchElementObj.group(0) : ", matchElementObj.group(0)

    for matchAttributesObj in re.finditer( r'\s\w+=(?:\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*"|[^\'"][^\s>]*)(?=\s|>)', string, re.M|re.I|re.S):
        print "matchAttributesObj.group(0) : ", matchAttributesObj.group(0)
```

**Output**

```
-------
matchElementObj.group(0) :  <a href="i.like.kittens.com" NotRealAttribute=' true="4>2"' class=Fonzie>
matchAttributesObj.group(0) :   href="i.like.kittens.com"
matchAttributesObj.group(0) :   NotRealAttribute=' true="4>2"'
matchAttributesObj.group(0) :   class=Fonzie
```

Answer (score 2):

[Please don't use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1971805). Use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> html = """<a href='aaa' style='bbb'>"""
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> mytag = soup.find('a')
>>> print mytag['href']
aaa
>>> print mytag['style']
bbb
```

Or if you want a dictionary:

```
>>> print mytag.attrs
{'style': 'bbb', 'href': 'aaa'}
```

Comment: I know HTML parsers should be good choices but actually I don't think they can work for me. I need to modify the raw string.

Comment: @zhangyangyu Take a look at [this](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) perhaps